Isogeny classes for elliptic curves over quadratic field

Question. Is it possible for an elliptic curve $E$ over quadratic field $K$ to have two separate (yet connected) isogeny classes?

There are two $\mathbb{Z}/14\mathbb{Z}$ elliptic curves, $E_1$ and $E_2$, over $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{430})$ mentioned on p. 100 in

L. Halbeisen, N. Hungerbühler, A. Shamsi Zargar and M. Voznyy, A geometric approach to elliptic curves with torsion groups Z/10Z, Z/12Z, Z/14Z, and Z/16Z, Rad Hrvat. Akad. Znan. Umjet. Mat. Znan. $27$ (2023), 87-109, Rad HAZU: 443908.

SetClassGroupBounds("GRH");
K := QuadraticField(430);
E1 := EllipticCurve([0, -214412*K.1 + 4876337, 0, -342516252672*K.1 + 7101936009216, 0]);       // for u = 11/5
E2 := EllipticCurve([0, -62694626 + 1548432*K.1, 0, 1179302691510625 - 52966130778000*K.1, 0]); // for u = -3/8

$E_1$ and $E_2$ are definitely not isomorphic as confirmed by Magma. They also don't seem to be isogenous, e.g. because the basis of their conductors is different, and Magma tools can't seem to map one to another.
Regardless, it is possible to map independent points $P_i$ on $E_1$ to $Q_i$ on $E_2$, see my Magma code snippet Z14.m.
Therefore, it looks like $E_1$ and $E_2$ are images of the same object and represent an elliptic curve $E$ over quadratic field $K$, but have two separate isogeny classes.

The conjugate of $E_{2}$ is $2$-isogenous to $E_{1}$.

As to the question on top: No, being isogenous is an equivalence relation.

@JeremyRouse Thank you, Jeremy! I know that. What would it mean for automatic mapping $E_1$ -> $E_2$ in Magma? (Are there any working commands in Magma to automatically create a map from $E_1$ to $E_2$ (not to a conjugate of $E_2$)?) And what would $E_1$ being isogenous to a conjugate of $E_2$ mean for $E_1$ and $E_2$ being considered isogenous or non-isogenous?

@ChrisWuthrich Thank you, Chris! Then, because my snippet Z14.m shows how to map $P_i$ on $E_1$ to $Q_i$ on $E_2$, does it mean that $E_1$ and $E_2$ should be considered isogenous? And is there a way to build a map from $E_1$ to $E_2$ automatically, letting Magma/Sage/etc. find a conjugate connection by itself, without us providing/hinting it?

Part of the definition of an isogeny is that it is a morphism of projective curves. The two maps on $K$-rational points that you are considering are of quite different nature.

@ChrisWuthrich Got it, thank you! Instead of isogeny, any chance for a specific name in this case?

I would call it "isogeny to the conjugate". Another possible name is "morphism over $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Q$".
